# How to add a game over function in this Doodle Jump game in sfml?

Tags: c++, sfml

How to add a game over? If you are not familiar with the Doodle Jump game, it is where a character will need to bounce off a platform to progress. But if the  player doesnt land on the platform, the game is over.

But in my case, even if I dont land on a platform, the game still continues.

`

```
    #include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
    #include <time.h>
    using namespace sf;

    struct point
    {
        int x, y;
    };

    int main()
    {
        srand(time(0));

        RenderWindow app(VideoMode(400, 533), "Doodle Game!");
        app.setFramerateLimit(60);

        Texture t1, t2, t3;
        t1.loadFromFile("C:/Users/Dani/Documents/GAMES SFML/16_Games/02 Doodle Jump/images/background.png");
        t2.loadFromFile("C:/Users/Dani/Documents/GAMES SFML/16_Games/02 Doodle Jump/images/platform.png");
        t3.loadFromFile("C:/Users/Dani/Documents/GAMES SFML/16_Games/02 Doodle Jump/images/mark.png");

        Sprite sBackground(t1), sPlat(t2), sPers(t3);

        point plat[20];

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            plat[i].x = rand() % 400;
            plat[i].y = rand() % 533;
        }

        int x = 100, y = 100, h = 200;
        float dx = 0, dy = 0;

        while (app.isOpen())
        {
            Event e;
            while (app.pollEvent(e))
            {
                if (e.type == Event::Closed)
                    app.close();
            }

            if (Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::Right)) x += 3;        
            if (Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::Left)) x -= 3;

            dy += 0.2;
            y += dy;
            if (y > 500)  dy = -10;

            if (y < h)
                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)    
                {
                    y = h;
                    plat[i].y = plat[i].y - dy;
                    if (plat[i].y > 533) { plat[i].y = 0; plat[i].x = rand() % 400; }
                }

            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                if ((x + 50 > plat[i].x) && (x + 20 < plat[i].x + 68)
                    && (y + 70 > plat[i].y) && (y + 70 < plat[i].y + 14) && (dy > 0))  dy = -10;

            sPers.setPosition(x, y);

            app.draw(sBackground);
            app.draw(sPers);
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)    
            {
                sPlat.setPosition(plat[i].x, plat[i].y);
                app.draw(sPlat);
            }

            app.display();
        }

        return 0;
    }
```

`

Thank you, all of your answers will be appreciated.

Comment: You need to detect a collision between `sPers` and (I guess) the bottom of the screen and then either run a new loop that ignores input, or rewrite your game loop to support different modes (playing or game over)